# ws:// over https:// - mixed content

Tags: javascript, web, websocket, content-security-policy, mixed-content

I've got trouble with js app - i've got website over https, but i need to connect with external device over ws - this is ONLY option, that this device can connect and response.

I'm getting error

```
Mixed Content: 
The page at 'https://(...).html' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 
'ws://192.168.(...).(...)/(...)'. 
This request has been blocked; 
this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

How can i get over it? Is some CSP-Policy option to avoid this?
WS is only option to connect - WSS is not a solution here.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to set up a proxy which can accept WSS connections and forwards it to your device.

Comment: You need a ssl certificate on your websocket server and change your http protocol to be `wss://`

Comment: @Nicolas - I can't - this is an external device in LAN, which i'm connecting via JS API

Comment: well, try changing your http protocol to `wss://` and check if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Nicolas The. Device. In. Question. Does. Not. Accept. WSS. Connections. So changing it will just result in a connection error.

Comment: You should be able to use a Content-Security-Policy of `connect-src ws://hostname.of.your.device/` to allow a plaintext websocket connection, provided that no other `connect-src` policy denies that access.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/ for the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

Your ws connection on an HTTPS page is considered active mixed content and is blocked by most browsers, CSP can't change that. As @deceze suggests a proxy accepting WSS is your best option. Downgrading to HTTP is another option, but not a good one.