# Using Content-Security-Policy to allow ws connections on https website

Tags: javascript, websocket, https, content-security-policy, ws

I have a HTTPS website which needs to communicate with a backend securely. I also need it to be able to interface with some hardware that only accepts ws connections (NOT wss). I am wondering whether it is possible (and if so, exactly how) to connect with this hardware. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59051080/6446602) that setting the Content-Security-Policy header to certain values can help enable this. I was wondering if anyone knows whether this approach will work, or if they have suggestions for any other approaches.

Comment: Access from `https:` to `ws:` means mixed content and it's block by Same Origin Policy, not by Content Security Policy. Therefore on `https:` page you can use `wss:` only. To convert `wss:` to `ws:` you can use third-party proxies like Cloudflare, or your own such as Nginx.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering whether how these reverse proxies would work and where I can find how to set them up on the ESP 8266 (which I've read is not super powerful). Also will services like Cloudflare work without internet (but a local network connection?)

Comment: Cloudflare definitely will not work without internet. Also httpS: / wsS: connections require a third party to verify and validate the SSL certificate, so internet is required. Therefore in the internal LAN the `http:` is used.